# Como passar resposta de um comando como argumento para outro comando?

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal

No linux eu faço algo como para pegar a resposta de um comando e passar como argumento para outro:

```
./program `ruby -e"puts 'Oh' * 3"`
```

No caso o que está entre os acentos (`ruby -e"puts 'Oh' * 3"`) será executado e o retorno será passado como argumento para o `program`.

Como posso fazer isso em Windows?

Eu pensei em criar um arquivo batch e executar o programa com o argumento, mais eu preciso só do comando, não executar dentro arquivo batch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi o que você precisa é passar o **resultado** do comando `ruby` como argumento para outro programa, no windows acredito que precisará armazenar o valor em uma variavel, maneiras que consegui chegar ao resultado foram:

### Armazenar o resultado em um arquivo

Desta maneira vai gerar um arquivo chamado `resultado.tmp` com a resposta do comando executado com `ruby` e em seguida irá setar este valor na variável, logo após apaga o arquivo (pois não vai mais usar):

```
ruby -e"puts 'Oh ' * 3" > resultado.tmp
set COMANDO_RUBY=<resultado.tmp
del resultado.tmp
programa.exe %COMANDO_RUBY%
```

### FOR e usebackq

Temos a opção de usar o [FOR](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) e ele possui a opção chamada `usebackq` que faz com o que esteja entre os acentos seja executado:

```
`string que será executada`
```

O comando deve ficar assim:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %i IN (`ruby -e"puts 'Oh ' * 3"`) DO SET COMANDO_RUBY=%i
programa.exe %COMANDO_RUBY%
```